# React Error: Each child in a list should have a unique key prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

What's wrong with the following:

```js
<List>
  {sections.map(section => (
    <>
      {section.header && <ListSubheader key={section.header}>{section.header}</ListSubheader>}
      {section.items
        .filter(item => new RegExp(itemsFilter, 'i').test(item.value))
        .map(item => {
          const labelId = `multi-select-filter-list-checkbox-label-${item.key}`;
          return (
            <ListItem key={item.key} role={undefined} dense button onClick={handleToggle(item)}>
              <ListItemIcon>
                <Checkbox
                  className={checkboxClasses.root}
                  edge="start"
                  checked={checked.indexOf(item) !== -1}
                  tabIndex={-1}
                  disableRipple
                  color="primary"
                  inputProps={{ 'aria-labelledby': labelId }}
                />
              </ListItemIcon>
              <ListItemText
                id={labelId}
                primary={item.value}
                primaryTypographyProps={{
                  variant: 'body1'
                }}
              />
            </ListItem>
          );
        })
      }
    </>
  ))}
</List>
```

I believe I'm providing the keys; where is the error?

Comment: Do you have duplicate keys in your items?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `key` prop should be provided for the wrapping tag.

Replace `<>` with `<React.Fragment>` and apply a key to it.

```
<React.Fragment key={section.header}>
```

Answer (score 1):

As [kind-user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6695924/kind-user) user stated you should add key to the wrapping tag.
Key is the only attribute that can be passed to .

Note: When you are passing a key to <>, you can't use this shorthand.
Rather use

```
<React.Fragment key={yourKey}> 
... 
<React.Fragment>
```